# Is it possible to run wine in containerd/ kubernetes CRI-O?

Tags: kubernetes, containerd, cri-o

Just wondering if deprecation of dockershim makes it still possible to run wine, windows processes in kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

No Docker had little to do with the running container, its only job was to monitor the stdout sterror of the pid1 of the container, and to catch the exit code.  Any process that can run on Linux can run inside of a container, it is all about the amount of isolation you wrap the processes with. You might need to loosen the security or not use all of the namespaces, but if a container image works with Docker it WILL work with CRI-O, Podman or Containerd.